# 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native-ios, onesignal

I am trying to build my react native app on Xcode but for some reason I am getting 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found. This is happening after tried to add OneSignal push notification library.

Initially it was complaining about libRTCAnimation but this I fixed by adding the libRTCAnimation.a into Link Binary with Libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error when trying to install Onesignal into detached expo project. I fixed it to do next things:

1. Remove one signal path from Header Search Path
2. Unlink onesignal module - react-native unlink react-native-onesignal
3. Added podspec from this [link](https://github.com/danieljvdm/react-native-onesignal/blob/620717a0027538999cd98e1f225d0e4d9a804445/react-native-onesignal.podspec)
4. Added next code into pod file:

   pod 'react-native-onesignal', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'
5. do `pod install'

Comment: thnx , the build went successful! still I don't get why we have to do in in this way as this is different from official documentation, but seems working :), thnx a lot!